# Error trying to run packer in AzureChinaCloud

Tags: azure, packer, azure-china

I am trying to build a VM image from `packer` configuration using the following command:

```sh
    packer build \
        -var base_img=$base_img \
        -var client_id=$client_id \
        -var client_secret=$client_secret \
        -var tenant_id=$tenant_id \
        -var subscription_id=$subscription_id \
        -var az_cloud_environment_name=China \
        -only=azure-arm \
        packer.json
```

However, I am getting the following error and I could not find what it means and what the resolution of it is:
`Build 'azure-arm' errored: packer-azure application not set up for Azure environment "AzureChinaCloud"`

Have anyone seen something like this?

Comment: Could it be that you are not properly passing on your `client_id`and `client_secret` to your packer file? How did you use those values there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should only happen if you use the "quick start" device code flow - see e.g. https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/5034.

It should not happen if you pass your own `clientId` and `clientSecret`. You probably did not use them correctly in your packer file

```
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "azure-arm",

      "client_id": "{{user `client_id`}}",
      "client_secret": "{{user `client_secret`}}",

      "vm_size": "Standard_DS2_v2"
    }
  ],
```